# How to do build variants in shake?

Tags: shake-build-system

How can pass parameters in shake and then use them in our rules? I would like to make some equivalents of:

`make ARCH=x86_64`
or
`make DEBUG=YES`
etc...

For now i've been using enviroment variables and `getEnv` function to simulate these.
How can i make a dependency on a given parameter (environment variable) so that it can be read once in a build, store it somewhere and access it from multiple rules?

e.g. For now i am doing getEnv multiple times in multiple rules but during compilation time the enviroment variable can change. Also for example a debug flag can alter both compiler and linker flags meaning that the info would be needed to be available in both link and compile output rules.

Comment: "but during compilation time the enviroment variable can change" - can you clarify? Environment variables are captured at the start of a process, so won't change during a run, unless you call something like `setEnv`.

Comment: The other question is do you want changing `DEBUG=YES` to `DEBUG=NO` to change all rules that depended on that setting (rebuilding most of your project), or just ignore the change, or build to a different directory?

Comment: On the first comment: Well thats something i forgot about so scratch that.
On the second comment: Yes i want to change all the rules that depend on that setting to change. For example, the compile/link flags will change and the output directories too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing approach of using environment variables should work, and since environment variables are already tracked by Shake, one approach is to parse `DEBUG=YES` and turn it into an environment variable. For example:

```
main = shakeArgsWith shakeOptions [] $ \_ args -> do
    let (vars,files) = partition ('=' `elem`) args
    forM_ vars $ \v -> let (a,'=':b) = break (== '=') v in setEnv a b
    return $ Just $ if null files then rules else want files >> withoutActions rules

rules :: Rules ()
rules = ...
```

Since environment variables are local to a process (and their child processes), this will probably work fine.

Of course, storing such information in the environment variables is a bit ugly. You can create your own oracle to store the information instead:

```
main = shakeArgsWith shakeOptions [] $ \_ args -> do
    let (vars,files) = partition ('=' `elem`) args
    let vars2 = [(a,b) | v <- vars, let (a,'=':b) = break (== '=') v]
    return $ Just $ do
        global <- addOracle $ \(Global x) -> return $ lookup x vars2
        if null files then rules global else want files >> withoutActions (rules global)

newtype Global = Global String deriving (Show,Typeable,Eq,Hashable,Binary,NFData)

rules :: (Global -> Action (Maybe String)) -> Rules ()
rules global = undefined
```

Now, instead of writing the information into an environment variable with `setEnv`, we store it in an oracle with `addOracle`, which will still be tracked and not conflict with any other environment-variable pieces.

Comment: Fantastic solutions! The shakeArgsWith entrypoint is everything i wanted. The oracle feature seems pretty neat too, but its kinda hard to understand from the documentation. I'll give it a shot though :P! Thanks for answering!

Comment: The best docs are at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:addOracle. They are one of the more complex aspects of Shake though.